# the sum of two columns in laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel, filter, group-by, sum

Please help me the sum of two columns in Laravel, like
[image: screenshot of a table]

My controller looks like this:

```php
  $rekap= DB::table('skpds')
                  ->join('usulans','skpds.idSkpd','=','usulans.idSkpd')
                  ->join('usulanhonors','skpds.idSkpd','=', 'usulanhonors.idSkpd')

                  ->groupBy('nama_skpd')

                  ->get( array(
                    DB::raw( 'SUM(usulans.apbd) AS apbd' ),
                    DB::raw( 'min(usulanhonors.jumlah_usulan_gaji) AS jumlah_usulan_gaji' ),
                     DB::raw( 'sum(apbd + jumlah_usulan_gaji) AS semua' ),
                    'nama_skpd'
                    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass multiply sign between two columns like

```
DB::raw('sum(quantity*per_qty) AS total')
```

Comment: Your welcome bro... if it solved you problem then do not forget to mark as right answer with upvote.